# How to boot Snow Leopard bootable usb with Clover or any other hackintosh bootloader?

Tags: usb, osx-snow-leopard, uefi, bootloader

So I followed the tutorial in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/383235/create-a-bootable-usb-drive-from-a-dmg-file-on-windows) answer and created a "bootable" USB from my OS X snow leopard '.dmg' installation media. The problem is that my Clover EFI bootloader doesn't seem to recognize the usb as bootable (and doesn't even add it in the boot devices menu). I don't know if that could have anything to do with the fact that I've rEFInd as my primary bootloader and so Clover EFI is chain-loaded.

Any ideas how to boot this usb? Maybe use different bootloader?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: @Tetsujin Interesting - somewhere I read that such question are allowed - I bet it was rather stackoverflow then here (ah yes - it was [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11104/what-is-the-policy-on-discussing-osx86-or-hackintoshes)).